# Query with Less Than AND Greater Than time

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, time

Please can you guys help me check if my syntax is correct. I don't get any errors using this code but I just wanted few opinions on whether I'm doing it right or not.

I'm using a multi-site Wordpress installation and I'm checking to see if the featured blog is older than a day but less than a week old:

```
/* Work out blog of the day */
$featured_id = get_option('featured_blog'); # Current ID
$featured_time = get_option('featured_time'); # Current Time

if($featured_time > time()-86400 && $featured_time < time()-604800) // more than 1 Day ago but less than a week
{
    $query = "SELECT blog_id FROM `wp_blogs` WHERE public = '1' and archived = '0' and spam = '0' and deleted = '0' AND blog_id NOT IN ('".$featured_id."', '1','27') ORDER BY rand() limit 1";
    $featured_id = $wpdb->get_var($query);
    update_option('featured_blog', $featured_id);
    update_option('featured_time', time());
}
```

Comment: You're doing it right if there is no error. To determine if it is good or not, you may consider the difference between system time and database time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_blogs, the column blog_id is int, so you should not enclose the values in quotes

```
select ... where ... and blog_id NOT IN (".$featured_id.", 1,27) ...
```

Same for columns `public`, `spam` and `deleted`.

Besides that, which isn't a real problem, I can't spot any syntax error.
But contrary to your title, you don't use the time in your query.

To the `if()` statement, this will never become true, because `$featured_time` cannot be `> now - 86400` and `< now-604800` at the same time. If you want the condition as in your comment, say

```
if ($featured_time < time()-86400 && $featured_time > time()-604800)
```

On a `time()`-line this looks more or less like this

```
0          now-604800   now-86400      1354618129
+----------+------------+--------------+
|          |            |              |
1.1.1970   a week ago   24 hours ago   now
```

So, if `$featured_time` should be between a week ago and a day ago, it must be greater than a week ago (> now - 604800) and less than a day ago (< now - 86400).

Comment: If i read that correct you are saying that  if(featured_time < time()-86400 (less than a day) && $featured_time > time()-604800 (greater than a week) is that right ? because i thought it was right the other way around that it's older than a day but not older than a week?

Comment: @DFreeman Please look at the updated answer, I hope it is more clear now.